# how to save alert dialog with share preference

Tags: android

What I want to do it's to save the last state using SharedPreference but I don't know what it's my mystake. I say that it's not saving because when I rotate the screen pops up again the alertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog")
.setMessage("Startup Button Visibility:")
.setPositiveButton("Hidden", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        if(buttonVisible == true)
        {
            myLayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
            myLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


      SharedPreferences myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
      boolean storedPreference = myPrefs.getBoolean("Skip", true);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
      if(storedPreference != false)
      {
          storedPreference= true;
      }
      editor.putBoolean("Skip", storedPreference);
      editor.commit();
    }
 })

 .show();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is all working correctly, but you are saving the same value you just read:

```
  int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("Skip", 0);
  editor.putInt("Skip", storedPreference);
```

while you need, at some point, change it to `1` to make any real effect otherwise it is always `0`. Your code also lack any condition related to `Skip` so it will show the dialog anyway. And I'd rather use `Bool` instead of `Int`

Comment: I have edited and changed what you said but it's not working... any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this just put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your Activity code in the Manifest file. This will automatically handle the screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("Skip", 1);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      if(storedPreference==1)
      {
        storedPreference = 0;
      }
      editor.putInt("Skip", storedPreference);
      editor.commit();

now after this u should check for 0, where trying stop the pop up of the dialog box
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new in android  and I don't know which value you refers to

Comment: Still not working :/ and I have done what you told me and still pops up the dialog